# Need help to understand Inheritance. Which kind of Inheritance do I have to use?

Tags: inheritance, uml, abstract, class-diagram

I have problems with creating a UML-class-diagram.
It would be nice if you can give me some tips.

My concrete problem is that I do not know how to solve the following idea:

There are **Milestones** which contain **Maintasks** (like a TODO Task).
The **Maintasks** contain **Subtasks**.
But **Maintasks** and **Subtasks** have the same attributes and probably the same operations. 
The **Taskmanager** is for handling interaction and information with **Milestones**, **Maintasks** and Sub**strong text**tasks.

Sorry for my bad english ;D

So my idea is to solve it like this:

[My UML-classdiagram idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KENl.png)

Answer (score 0):

In general I understand what you are proposing in your UML. I note that you have Main and Sub Tasks separated out rather than having a self-aggregating Task, which may be a simpler way to solve the problem though would imply recursion you might not want to allow? You could simplify also by having one composition and putting a state attribute on the sub or main task classes (active/complete). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

How do you think about that?
https://i.imgur.com/xzav7Kc.png

Comment: the arrow used between enum and task should be pointed towards Task because Task use enum not enum use task.